# MVC Newtonsoft JSON CustomJsonConverter

Tags: json, converters

I have a web resource that outputs JSON as below:

```
[{"returnValue":
[{"facility":"DRIO","recrd_desc":"DEFAULT","update_time":{"$date":1509128545000},"control_num":1,"starttime":{"$date":1506830400000},"endtime":{"$date":4102462799000},"can_exchange_rate":2000},
{"facility":"DRIO","recrd_desc":"TEMP","update_time":{"$date":1521229607000},"control_num":37,"starttime":{"$date":1513040240000},"endtime":{"$date":1544576240000},"can_exchange_rate":2112},
{"facility":"DRIO","recrd_desc":"TEMP 3","update_time":{"$date":1521229399000},"control_num":38,"starttime":{"$date":1544576580000},"endtime":{"$date":1576112580000},"can_exchange_rate":2000}],
"ok":1.0}]
```

I deserialize the above Json to my model as:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

namespace CSCApi.Models
{
    public class FareChartTypeResponse
    {
        public List<FareChartType> ReturnValue { get; set; }
        public decimal ok { get; set; }
    }

    public class FareChartType
    {
        public string facility { get; set; }
        public string recrd_desc { get; set; }
        public Update_Time update_time { get; set; }
        public int control_num { get; set; }
        public Starttime starttime { get; set; }
        public Endtime endtime { get; set; }
        public int can_exchange_rate { get; set; }        
    }

    public class Update_Time
    {        
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "$date")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(LongToStringConverter))]
        public string date { get; set; }
    }

    public class Starttime
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "$date")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(LongToStringConverter))]
        public string date { get; set; }
    }

    public class Endtime
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "$date")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(LongToStringConverter))]
        public string date { get; set; }
    }

    public class LongToStringConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return typeof(System.Int64).Equals(objectType);
        }
        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.Integer)
            {
                throw new Exception(
                    String.Format("Unexpected token parsing date. Expected Integer, got {0}.",
                    reader.TokenType));
            }

            var ticks = (long)reader.Value;

            var date = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
            //date = date.AddSeconds(ticks).ToLocalTime();
            date = date.AddSeconds(ticks);
            //return date;
            string dateString = ((DateTime)date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            return dateString;
        }
        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            long ticks;                       
            if (value is string)
            {
                DateTime _d = Convert.ToDateTime(value);
                var epoc = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);                
                var delta = _d - epoc;
                if (delta.TotalSeconds < 0)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
                        "Unix epoc starts January 1st, 1970");
                }
                ticks = (long)delta.TotalSeconds;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Expected date object value.");
            }
            writer.WriteValue(ticks);
        }
    }
}
```

The above custom converter doesn't seem to be working. What I am trying to do is convert the $date(which is a unix timestamp) into a datetime string(in a particular format) when reading and outputting a long when writing. 
I would appreciate if somebody could help me out.

I tried decorating with UnixDateTimeConverter, but it didn't work either.

Thanks
NH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unix Timestamp from the we resource was in milliseconds that I parsed to convert to time string. It works fine now.